# Priniting 4 lists together, unequal number of elements

Tags: python, list, printing

If there are 4 lists

```
items = []
item_links = []
prices = []
images =[]
```

Is there a way to print these lists together? I mean, the first item of 1st list together with the first element of the third and fourth list. Thanks.

Comment: are their sizes same?

Comment: Just mentioned..no..sorry, will put that in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`

```py
for item, link, price, image in zip(items, item_links, prices, images):
    print(item, link, price, image)
```

Comment: tried that..says, list index out of range, maybe the lists do not have equal elements

Comment: The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted, not-equal length is ok.

Comment: Outputs nothing :(

Comment: @Abhishek Rai is any list empty?

Comment: @Abhishek Rai I think you got your answer.

Comment: @JasonYang , Sorry One of the list is empty..will just check.